# Как правильно сделать MySQL запрос с групировкой по столбцу

Tags: php, mysql

есть такая таблица

```
id    |  storesId   |      productId   |     date            | quntity  |   catId
______|_____________|__________________|_____________________|__________|_________
11    |     1       |        1         |   1475269200        |  100     |    1
______|_____________|__________________|_____________________|__________|_________
12    |     1       |        4         |   1475269100        |   10     |    2
______|_____________|__________________|_____________________|__________|_________
13    |     2       |        2         |   1452027600        |  100     |    1
```

пытался организовать запрос такого вида

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND 1452029600 GROUP BY storesId
```

что пытался сделать:
мне надо вывести в одной таблице по `storesId` все значения к примеру

```
storesId   |      productId   |     date              | quntity  |   catId
1          |        1,4       | 1475269200,1475269100 |  100,10  |   1,2
2          |        2         | 1452027600            |  100     |   1
```

а получается

```
stores 1 storesId 1date 1475269200  quntity 100 catId 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT storesId, GROUP_CONCAT(productId), GROUP_CONCAT(date), GROUP_CONCAT(quantity), GROUP_CONCAT(catId) 
table WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND 1452029600 GROUP BY storesId
```

Таким образом данные из перечисленные Вами колонок будут разделены запятыми.

Позволю себе пару замечаний:

- есть ограничение на кол-во знаков. БД соберет все через запятую, но остановится после (кажется) 1024 знаков. Правда, это можно регулировать (`@@group_concat_max_len`).
- изначальный сепаратор - запятая. В некоторых случаях Вам может быть удобно его заменить (читайте в доках)
- также для сокращения объемов может быть имеет смысл кое-где выбирать уникальные данные. Например: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT catIds)`

Вот доки на функцию: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Да сепапротор особо не нужно. Мне надо просто все значения получить но по storesId

Comment: Просто в Вашем примере нет текстовых полей, поэтому запятая как сепаратор проблем не составит. Ну а насчет "все значения" - будьте внимательны с объемами. :)

Comment: пишу так SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT storesId
ORDER BY storesId ASC 
SEPARATOR  ', ' ) AS stores
FROM  `poductctores` 
id  storesId productId        date          quntity   catId  stores
11     1            1           1475269200      100      1      1

GROUP BY storesId получаю id 11 
storesId 1   productId 1 date 1475269200 quntity 100 catId 1
stores 1  что не так

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` нужно применять к КАЖДОМУ полю, которое Вы хотите получить. `GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT storesId)` даст вам только `storesIDs`. Вам надо перечислить их все. Т.е. заменить `*` на перечисление: `GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT productId), GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT catIDs)` и т.д. Полу, по которому идет группировка (в Вашем случае `storesId`) в `GROUP_CONCAT()` засовывать не надо - оно итак группируется